# Is there a way of just having one pair of <% %> in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I wish to print the current directory as a list.  The recommended method of doing this in the 3 books I've looked at is

```
<ul>
<% for file in Dir.glob('*') %>
   <li><%= file %> <li/>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I think this looks rather clumsy.  I'd like to do something like

```
<ul>
<%
   for file in Dir.glob('*')
      xxx "<li>" + file + "<li/>"
   end
%>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to know is what xxx is called.  What I'd like to avoid is having lots of <% and %> all over the place.

Comment: You are looking for `concat`

Comment: @UriAgassi Should we reopen the question ? I think although it is duplicate, but the improvement can be suggested in the comment itself.

Comment: @UriAgassi Ok.. I agree

Comment: I'll rephrase the question

Comment: @cup - what you ask for is kind of counter to the whole purpose of ERB (which means _embedded_ ruby...), but the answers in the question we are pointing you to solve the problem you are referring to - `xxx` is `concat`...

Comment: If you want to avoid a lot of the `<%= ... %>` jazz, you could try a meta-markup like [HAML](http://haml.info/) that largely bypasses all of this. Additionally, as a matter of Ruby style, `for` is hardly ever used. That would be better written as `Dir.glob('*').each do |file|`